# Error when using conditional breakpoint with instanceof.Is it me or eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

My condition for break :
event instanceof org.geomajas.gwt.client.widget.event.SearchEvent
I have tried other variations like event instanceof SearchEvent / with parantheses and with/out ";"

The error : Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements

The solution: ?

BTW I'm using jdk 1.6.25

Answer (score 5):

```
return event instanceof org.geomajas.gwt.client.widget.event.SearchEvent;
```

should do the trick